# L'Hôpital or L'Hospital?

Tags: terminology, math-history, mathematical-french

This may be a stupid question but I just want clarification about the use of the name of this rule. Well, most of the time what I see is *L'Hospital's Rule*, like in Baby Rudin and many other places. Occasionally, though, I do see what seems to be the "more correct" form *L'Hôpital's Rule* (like in Wikipedia). I believe the latter is the correct version, because the rule was indeed named after *Guillaume de l'Hôpital*. (see the [wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)).

But why is the former version so commonly used (much more than the latter I think)?  The only reason I can imagine is the popularity of the English language. However, though *hôpital* does mean *hospital* in English, isn't it totally ridiculous to translate *Règle de L'Hôpital* into *L'Hospital's Rule* (just because the corresponding English word *hospital* happens to make sense)? What's more, how are we supposed to pronounce *L'Hospital*? In an English way or in a French way? In the first place, I think it is confusing to combine a French article with an English word, and in the second, it is even more confusing to use *l'* in place of *le/la* since in English the *h* in *hospital* isn't even mute. Anyway *L'Hospital* makes little sense to me..

Comment: see here http://www.dict.cc/?s=Regeln+von+de+l%5C'H%C3%B4pital+%5Bauch+de+l%5C'Hospital%5D

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks. But undoubtedly *L'Hospital* is used everywhere.

Comment: i think it must be De L'Hospital  and we say rules of Bernoulli- De L'Hospital

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I don't know how to pronounce *l'hospital*.  It  makes little sense to combine a French article with an English word. (And in English that "h" isn't even mute...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 17<sup>th</sup> and 18<sup>th</sup> centuries, the name was commonly spelled *l'Hospital*, and, as far as I learned when I was a student, even himself used to spell his name that way. However, with time going, many French spellings have been altered: in particular, the silent *s* has been removed and replaced with the circumflex over the preceding *o* making *l'Hôpital*. The former spelling is still used in English with no circumflex.

Comment: You can italicize text by using asterisks (`like *this*`) which is better than pretending it is mathematics.

Comment: Thank u. So you mean *hôspital* is the archaic form of *hôpital* and over time the former spelling altered into the latter?

Comment: This is essentially a copy-paste from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_de_l'H%C3%B4pital#cite_note-1).

Comment: @Rahul. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: @Vim.  *hospital* (without circumflex) is effectively the archaic form of *hôpital*. In the same spirit *hostel* became *hôtel*

Answer (score 2):

I know you problem! I live in a city where English *is* popular, but people are not so good at it. I know for sure that it is pronounced without the 's', (L'Hôpital's Rule). But whenever I ask a question related to it to my teacher, instead of saying "lop-it-als" I say "eL-Hos-pi-tals", and then only he understands. So I don't think it will be a problem, just ensure that when you are speaking in front of knowledgeable mathematicians, speak the right way. But if you encounter a situation like mine, the shorter way is better! (y) 
Those who are saying that in English you have to pronounce is like "L Hospital", I don't think it is legitimate, because suppose you were born in Spain, and (just for an example), your name was "Jalapeno", then in England, if people call you "Jai-le-peeno", will it seem good? Now rest is in your hands.