# How to pronounce "L'Hospital"?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation

How to pronounce "L'Hospital"? Some people pronounce like "lapital". When I was in 12th standard, some teachers used to pronounce "lapital" and some used to pronounce "L hospital".

Comment: Looking at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), my understanding is that it should be pronounced Lo as in go, pi as in bee, tal as in trap.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yep thats correct as you said...L'hôpital

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaebTm9A1ng matches what I read and what I was taught in undergraduate.  (*Note: I was taught by a Parisian*)

Comment: Yes, it is a French name. In old french many words had a muted *s* now replaced by *^* (e.g. forestier-forêt, festif-fête, défenestrer-fenêtre, ...). So it reads the same as *hôpital*, and the youtube link given by JMoravitz is correct. Now it is possible that in old days, the pronunciation was the same, but the *s* not or less muted, it's yours to choose.

Comment: "Tal" as in "trap"????  Seriously?  The "a" in "trap" followed by an "l" is practically impossible, it seems to me. I always heard it as,  either as in "pal" (which matches your video) or as "tall" which, if wrong, matched my professors.

Comment: @fleablood a like the a in sat...I sat ...or like the first a in american

Comment: The "a" in "sat" and the first "a" is "american" are completely different.

Comment: See teh post [L'Hôpital or L'Hospital?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397736/lh%c3%b4pital-or-lhospital)

Answer (score 1):

**In American accent it will be pronounced as loh-pee-TAHL.**

*Further for this question, you can try the following link. It has recordings of "L'Hospital rule" being pronounced in many languages(accents).*

[Link with Recordings](http://www.pronouncekiwi.com/L'Hospital%20rule)

Comment: That link has it pronounced in English incorrectly across the board. It is not supposed to sound to like the English word hospital. It's like pronouncing Fourier with a hard r at the end but it's supposed to be silent, or pronouncing Weierstrauss with an w sound like in wire when it should sound like v because it's German.